# InfoWindow blinks when calling setContent() on Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I call the `setContent()` of an **already opened** `InfoWindow` of the Google Maps API v3, it blinks very fast (it hides the window, showing the map behind it and then shows the `InfoWindow` again) but is ugly and perceptive. Is there any way to update the content without blinking it ? I'm considering using a `div` inside it but I think that it should have a better way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set new content, infowindow is automatically closed and opened again. You can try it on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3PfU9/). If you uncomment `marker.infowindow.setContent()` and comment the other two lines, the behavior is basically the same. Sometimes it blinks, sometimes it does not.

```
$('button.change').live('click', function(){
    marker.infowindow.close();
    //marker.infowindow.setContent(getRandomContent());
    marker.infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

If you know which new content can replace the old one, you could make it with hidden div and change these two divs. There would be no blinking.